# Xamarin.iOS: Saving files to windows shared folder

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS app written using Xamarin. Is there a way to save some file (in my case Image) to a shared folder on Windows PC? iOS device and PC are in the same WiFi network, so I can get access to PC machine by IP address. But how can I save a file to that shared folder?
If that is possible I would be grateful for some code example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try [SharpCifs.Std?](https://github.com/ume05rw/SharpCifs.Std)
NuGet Package is [here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpCifs.Std/)

drives SMB on Xamarin.iOS, like this.

```
var file = new SmbFile("smb://UserName:Password@ServerName/ShareName/Folder/NewFileName.txt"));
file.CreateNewFile();
var writeStream = file.GetOutputStream();
writeStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Xamarin application (on iPad Pro 12.9") I kind of worked around this problem by activating FTP on my Windows10 machine (see Google how to do this) and then uploaded the image to the Windows folder via FTP:

```
private void UploadImage(UIImage image, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        string ftpPath = "ftp://192.168.47.79/"; // IP of my Windows10 pc
        string ftpTargetFilePath = $"{ftpPath}{fileName}";
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "ftp");

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ftpTargetFilePath);
        request.Credentials = credentials;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.UsePassive = false; // in my case I needed passive mode to be deactivated
        
        using (Stream imageStream = image.AsPNG().AsStream())
        {
            using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                imageStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Uploading Image: Failed! ({ex.Message})");
    }
}
```