# How to save files to a network drive from a Mac (C#)

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, file-sharing, network-drive

I've been doing some research on how to upload a JPG to a network drive. Much of the documentation I run across keeps using "WindowsIdentity" and "WindowsImpersonation" such as this one: [Copy file on a network shared drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive)

This Windows Identity is an issue because I'm writing this code on a Mac. It's for an iOS phone app. How should I go about doing this? I'm writing my application in C#. I need to send the image data in my application to the network drive, placing the image in the correct folder.How can this be accomplished writing code with a Mac? (can't use windows identity)

Comment: there are a lot of different types of "network share" and a lot of different authentication methods.  Which ones do you need to support?

Comment: Alright - I'm pretty new to this whole thing so bear with me here. I connect to the shared file network by adding my credentials, and it logs me onto the server. I believe I can only access it by being on the company's network. I can ask a coworker when they're around about specifics.

Comment: @Jason what do you mean by multiple types of network shares? can I have some examples so I know what exactly to research

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/network-address-formats-and-protocols-on-mac-mchlp1654/mac

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1226726/which-protocols-are-used-for-network-share-access

Comment: @Jason I went to connect to the server and SMB was in front of the server name. Does this help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765359/xamarin-ios-saving-files-to-windows-shared-folder

Comment: @Jason thank you! I wasn't searching for Xamarin specific answers, I guess that's where I was going wrong. You miss one keyword in a question and you are blocked off from potential solutions. I will definitely try this library and see how it works for me